# Insert local file path in json file

Tags: ios, json, swift, filepath

I am trying to insert paths of two local file folders in a json file in my project. My json file has two keys `"sprite"` and `"glyphs"` and I've included two file folders named `sprites` and `glyphs` which are to be the values of above two keys in json file. My json file looks like:

```
"sprite": "asset://sprites/sprite",
"glyphs": "asset://glyphs/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
```

But the code doesn't seems to locate them. I've also tried following, but doesn't worked

```
"sprite": "file:///sprites/sprite",
"glyphs": "file:///glyphs/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
```

Comment: "I've included two file folders named sprites and glyphs" Could you use FileManager to locate them? Especially getting the real path ?

Comment: Yes, but how to set a path as a key value in a json file?

Comment: json file wouldn't detect Filemanager class

Comment: Forget about JSON, can you locate your files inside your app? You need to be sure what path to use.

Comment: @Larme Yes, I can locate it's path.

Comment: I am asking how to insert that file path in a json file, not about how to get file path, please assist me on that.